# Add Auth0 bearer token to Angular HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, auth0

I am writing an `HttpInterceptor` that will add a bearer token to an outgoing request. The bearer token to be obtained by calling method `getAccessTokenSilently`. Method is part of `Auth0` service and makes an http call to authorizer for token if not cached locally.

```typescript
    getAccessTokenSilently(options?: GetTokenSilentlyOptions): Observable<string>;
```

Basically my code has to do the following;

```typescript
    import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      constructor(public auth:AuthService) {}

      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const token = this.auth.getAccessTokenSilently();
        return next.handle(req.clone({ setHeaders: { token } }));
      }
    }
```

To get the token I need to subscribe to observer for `getAccessTokenSilently` but by the time the token is available, the method has already exited.

I tried using await function but it does not work because `getAccessTokenSilently` does not return a promise.

How do I pause my function while I wait for token to be available?

Answer (score 2):

'Pausing' the main thread of a web application is, and will always be, a terrible idea. Luckily you won't have to do that in this case, because you can use rxjs to achieve what you want to do. Something similar to the following should do the trick:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth.getAccessTokenSilently()
        .pipe(
            mergeMap((token) => {
                return next.handle(req.clone({ setHeaders: { token } }));
            })
        );
}
```

If you're planning to do more work with observables, you should definitely checkout rxjs and do a couple of tutorials.